# DialogFragment keeps displaying full screen (not in a dialog)

Tags: java, android, view, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` which contains a `WebView`. I create an instance of the `DialogFragment`within the activity and call the `show` method on it. Usually this displays it as a `Dialog` over the current view of the activity but randomly it will display it full screen as if I called the `setContentView` method. Here's the code within the activity:

```
    InternetDialog webDialog = new InternetDialog();
    webDialog.setUrl(mRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    webDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Twitter WebView");
```

Where `InternetDialog` is a class that extends `DialogFragment` and creates the `View` within the `onCreateDialog` method. I'm using the support library for an older Android OS version. So, my question is: why is the `DialogFragment` displaying full screen not as a Dialog?

**Edit:** Here is the code for the `InternetDialog` class:

```
    public class InternetDialog extends DialogFragment{//the soft keyboard won't show up
private String url;
WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internet_dialog, null);

    WebView web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web);
    EditText edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setFocusable(true);
    edit.requestFocus();
    web.loadUrl(url);
    this.webView = web;
    builder.setView(v);

    return builder.create();

}//end of onCreateDialog() method

public View getWebView(){
    return webView;
}

public String getUrl(){
    return this.url;
}//end of getUrl() method

public void setUrl(String url){
    this.url = url;
}//end of setUrl() method

}//end of DialogFragment class
```

And here's the `internet_dialog` `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wait, are you saying sometimes it shows as a dialog, but sometimes it displays full screen? If so, can you show your code for `InternetDialog`?

Comment: Yes, that's what seems to be happening, odd I know. I placed up the code for the `InternetDialog` class.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what the `internet_dailog` layout looks like too, but have you tried setting the `WebView` to a fixed height and width? I'm curious if the time of the page load is affecting the size of the view.

Comment: I have not tried setting the `WebView` to a specific size. However, I have noticed that once it displays full screen it will continue to do so every time I re-install via the `ADT`. The only time it will go back to a `Dialog` is if I delete the app off the device and then re-install.

Answer (score 0):

This is more fitting as a comment, but I can't comment yet... have you considered looking at your call to `setStyle` in `onCreate`? From the looks of the documentation, it looks like when you set the dialog's style, [STYLE_NO_FRAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#STYLE_NO_FRAME)
could be interfering with the window sizes since the resulting view depends entirely on the inflated view in `onCreateView`.